# Set image at proper position in Border layout in java swing

Tags: image, swing, border-layout

I'm using a JDialog inside which I have added a JPanel. Layout of Jpanel is BorderLayout. Now I have some information and an image to be shown in that panel. So I have added all information in Border.Center and add image in Border.south. But the image is not properly positioned. The following may help to understand:

[image]

The image is displayed at bottom and at horizontal center. But what I want is that image should be displayed at Top-Left corder of Border.south. How can I do this? Is it possible
?

**Edit:-**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JDialog dialog = new JDialog();
    dialog.setSize(350, 350);
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(panel);

    JEditorPane textPane = new JEditorPane();
    textPane.setContentType("text/html");
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
    buffer.append(String.format("<div><b>Name:</b>%s</div>", "Harry"));
    buffer.append(String.format("<div><b>Id:</b>%s</div>", "Joy"));
    textPane.setText(buffer.toString());

    panel.setBackground(Color.white);
    panel.add(textPane,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    JPanel jPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEADING));
    JLabel lbl = new JLabel("Image will be here.");
    lbl.setFont(new Font(Font.SANS_SERIF,0,40));
    jPanel.add(lbl);
    panel.add(jPanel,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    dialog.add(scroll);
    dialog.setVisible(true);
}
```

In this code I have added a JLabel ("Image will be here.") instead of image to represent the situation.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `JPanel` with a `FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT)` to the `SOUTH`.  Add the image to the JPanel and it should end up in the upper left of the `SOUTH` area.

Comment: @Andrew: By doing this image comes on left but not on top. I have also tried FlowLayout.Leading but same output.

Comment: @Harry:  I could ask: What else are you adding to the `JPanel`? or What is the preferred size of the `JPanel`?  or a dozen other questions, but instead I'll say - for better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html).  For as SSCCE of this nature, you might swap the image for a component intended to represent the image, generate the image in code, or hot-link to one available on the net (e.g. at my [media page](http://pscode.org/media/#image)).

Comment: @Andrew: What I find out is that border.south only takes height same as image height and therefore the space between text and image appears.

Comment: @Harry:  Which part of S-SC-C-E are you having trouble understanding?  Code snippets do *not* constitute an SSCCE.  Please read the link.

Comment: @Andrew: Yes not a SSCCE. it's my code. I thought posting my code will help more. Okay I'll post a small example soon.

Comment: @Andrew: I have updated code. Now if you want you can try the above code it will reproduce the problem I'm facing. Don't forget to change image path when trying to run it.

Comment: @Harry:  "Don't forget to change image path"  I could not be bothered changing an image path.  That is why I suggested 3 (count them) other possibilities for accounting for the image.  Unfortunately it seems I am failing to communicate my points to you, and don't have the knowledge of how to continue - so I won't.  Good luck with it.

Comment: @Andrew: Okay. Thanks for your help up to here. Anyways for others I have updated the code and added JLabel instead of image to represent the situation. :-)

Answer (score 0):

If someone knows `TableLayout`, it is easy to do with that.

```
double p = TableLayout.PREFERRED;
double f = TableLayout.FILL;
double[][] sizes = {
    {p,f},
    {p,p,f}
};

panel.setLayout(new TableLayout(sizes));

panel.add(textPane, "0,0, 1,0");
panel.add(jPanel, "0,1");
```